# Check email every amount of seconds

Tags: email

I have code that lights up every time I get a specific email. I am using twisted and want it to run this code every twenty seconds, but right now the code is just turning the light on when run and keeping it on (the light usually only runs for 10 seconds then shuts off) anyone know why twisted is doing this? or how to implement this.

```
import gmail
import unicornhat as unicorn
from light import light
import time
from twisted.internet import task
from twisted.internet import reactor

timeout = 20.0 # Sixty seconds

def doWork():

      g = gmail.login('email', 'password')
      unread = g.inbox().mail(subject="[Ardent Ink] Order")
      print unread[0].body
      total_messages = 0
      # none

      for message in unread:
            total_messages += 1

      if total_messages > 0:
            light()

            pass

l = task.LoopingCall(doWork)
l.start(timeout) # call every sixty seconds

reactor.run()
```

here is the code for the module light()

```
import time
import unicornhat as unicorn

def light():
    unicorn.set_layout(unicorn.AUTO)
    unicorn.rotation(0)
    unicorn.brightness(1.0)
    width,height= unicorn.get_shape()

    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            unicorn.set_pixel(x,y,255,255,255)
            unicorn.show()
            time.sleep(0.01)
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Your code works fine when I stub out the gmail calls and change `light()` to print something.  Maybe your problem is in your `light` module.

Comment: I have updated the post with the light() module code, which does run time.sleep, not sure if that is interfering with it.

Comment: So, I know next to nothing about unicornhat, but it seems to me in the above code you don't turn the light off.  If you're experimenting with the light in a standalone script, when the script exits, unicornhat might shutdown the lights as it exits.

Comment: What happens if you do `unicorn.off()`  right after `time.sleep(10)`?  Also, you might look at `unicorn.set_all()` instead of looping.